# How do I display JSON data to an HTML DOM Element after JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, express

I have two functions I am using to pull JSON from my server side to then display it to HTML.

The first function that pulls the data from the route handler is successfully pulling the data and parsing it successfully with JSON.parse() and displaying the needed information to the console without issue. I am not having and ajax or route handling issue...

Here is how I am dealing with the JSON first in my function called "projectInfo()":

```
        projInfo = JSON.stringify(data); 
        console.log("DEBUG DONE WITH CAPTURING project_info DATA: " );

        // This console.log() prints the JSON string 
        //   successfully pulled from route handler
        // var projInfo is a local string var declared in the scope of 
        //   this first function
        console.log("var projInfo: " + projInfo);

        // parse JSON data in projInfo and store in string var p
        // string var p is a local var declared inside of the scope 
        //   of this function
        p = JSON.parse(projInfo);
        console.log("Parsed Project JSON: " + p.Project);

        // update "Global" pInfo with the value of the JSON data for 
        //   "Project" as needed
        pInfo = p;
        console.log("What is inside of pInfo???: " + pInfo);
        // This last console.log prints [object Object] to console
        // How do I pul the value out of this Object?
```

The second function calls the first function in order to update a global variable with the parsed JSON data that I need to then display the global variable's data to the DOM element that I am trying to display.

Here is how I am trying to update my global var with a JSON Object in my function called "loginFun()":

```
               // Call projectInfo() in order to update Global pInfo  
               //   with the needed project info
                projectInfo();

                // This console.log() prints nothing...?
                console.log("projectInfo var data should be aa2: " + pInfo);


                document.getElementById("userBar").style.display = "";

                // This is where I try to Display pInfo in the DOM but I only get Undefined...?
                document.getElementById("signedinas").innerHTML = "<font face=\"verdana\" size =\"4\" color=\"white\">Logged in as: " + username + " Project: " + pInfo + " </font>";
```

When I JSON.parse() the data in the first function I run a console.log() statement and I get the needed data to print from a variable local to the function I am getting my JSON with using ajax and I verify that the function is in fact doing what I need so that part is good up until I get the [object Object] output.

I am having issues when I call this function from my second function to then try to use the global variable which should have the data stored.

when I try to use the global variable with the needed data I get an 'undefined'...

I have also tried returning the data that has been parsed in the first function to then storehttps://codepen.io/lopezdp/pen/owKGdJ the value returned into a local variable in the second function but I still get 'undefined'.

If you would like to see the complete code for both functions I have put them on a CodePen to make it easier at:

https://codepen.io/lopezdp/pen/owKGdJ

How can I get my Project Data to display in my DOM element?

**EDIT:** The JSON Data that I am using looks like this:

```
{"User":"aa2","Owner":"aa2_role","Status":"locked","Port":"5432","Description":"Transferred from CFS01 on Jun29","Project":"aa2","Server":"localhost"}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing a `JSON.stringify()` followed immediately by a `JSON.parse()`? Because that should theoretically end up being the same object your passed into `JSON.stringify()`...

Comment: I thought I should stringify the JSON data. Should I eliminate it?

Comment: You don't need to stringify and then immediately parse it. If you're stringifying it to send it to the server, that's fine.

Comment: If i dont stringify it I get an error when I try to parse it. I have to stringify it when it comes from the server and then I can parse it. So that's why it is there...

Comment: You get an error because it is already parsed by whatever framework you're using. You need neither stringify nor parse; remove both from your code. Or don't; it's just a waste of CPU cycles and if it doesn't slow you down it's not a big deal.

Comment: ok so i took them both out. and inside of my ajax function i am using: p = data['Project']; to get the data and it is printing to console but it still is not printing to DOM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your login function like this and it worked for me. I also eliminated the projectInfo() function!

```
var allMn = [];
var tags = [];
var pInfo = '';

function loginFun() {
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

if (username == "" || password == "") {
    alert("Required fields cannot be left blank.");
} else {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://139.169.63.170:' + port + '/login/' + username + "zlz" + password,       
        cache: false,   

        success: function (data) {

            // NEED SUB ROUTINE HERE FOR AJAX CALL DPL
            // Make async call to ccdd tool database to get new data
            // This collects allMn[] data!!!
            getMnJson();            
            // END SUB ROUTINE HERE

            // Checks to make sure user is logged in if not
            // the condition redirects user to loginFun()
            if (data.search("HTTP ERROR: ") != -1) {
                alert("Login Failed.");
                document.getElementById('username').value = "";
                document.getElementById('password').value = "";
                document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = "Login Failed";
                document.getElementById('searchRBar').style.display = "";
                loginFun();
            } else {

            login = 1;

                // Call projectInfo() in order to update pInfo with the needed project info
                //projectInfo();



                var projInfo = '';
                var p = '';

                // Get all Mn Data on startup tp display in DOM -DPL
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://139.169.63.170:' + port + '/role',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: true,    

                    success: function (data) {

                        // projInfo = JSON.stringify(data); 
                        console.log("DEBUG DONE WITH CAPTURING project_info DATA: " );

                        // console.log("var projInfo: " + projInfo);

                        // parse JSON data in projInfo
                        p = data['Project']; //JSON.parse(projInfo);
                        console.log("Parsed Project JSON: " + p);

                        // update "Global" pInfo with the value of the JSON data for "Project" as needed
                        pInfo = p;
                        console.log("What is inside of pInfo???: " + pInfo);



                        document.getElementById("signedinas").innerHTML = "<font face=\"verdana\" size =\"4\" color=\"white\">Logged in as: " + username + " Project: " + pInfo + " </font>";
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                        alert("Login Failed.");
                        document.getElementById('username').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('password').value = "";
                        console.log("Error. /role data access Error.");
                });





                console.log("projectInfo var data should be aa2: " + pInfo);


                document.getElementById("userBar").style.display = "";

                // Display pInfo in the DOM
                // document.getElementById("signedinas").innerHTML = "<font face=\"verdana\" size =\"4\" color=\"white\">Logged in as: " + username + " Project: " + pInfo + " </font>";

                $("div.create").children().remove();

                //-------------------------------------------------------------------END OF GLOBAL VARIABLES

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    cache: false
                });

                // get table data from proxy server on port 7071 DPL
                // NEED SUB ROUTINE HERE FOR AJAX CALL
                // Make call to server-side code to reload JSON data into table from port 7071
                pushJsonData();
                // END SUB ROUTINE HERE!!!

                // getTblJson();
            }
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("Login Failed.");
        document.getElementById('username').value = "";
        document.getElementById('password').value = "";
        console.log("Error. Need user Credentials");
    });
}
}
```